# Dynamic way to use setter and getter

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, accessor

Hello my problem is simple I have code which simplified looks like this

```
foo = OpenStruct.new
bar = OpenStruct.new

mappings.each do |k,v|
 eval "foo.#{k} = bar.#{v}"
end
```

I am trying to fix this `eval` use and not use it :) Figured out the right part but I do not know how to assign to left one. To access getter you could write.

```
 bar.send(v.to_sym)
 # not to sure how to access setter for foo
```

I am using **Ruby 1.8.7**, Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure about 1.8.7, but in newer Rubies this works:

```
foo.send("#{k}=".to_sym, bar.send(v.to_sym))
```

Also, in newer versions, `send` accepts strings as well, so you can omit `.to_sym`.

Comment: Thats it, hvala Mladene :) Time to lose this noob eval :)

Comment: nnč ;) Not sure what are you using it for, but perhaps you could ditch `OpenStruct` and use plain hashes, sometimes it's less trouble in the end.

Comment: This is part of big beast, using metadata mappings to generate shell tables via `hirb`. Due to requirements of `hirb` which works with instances this was most elegant solution.